# How to get the variable name of DocVariable?

Tags: c#

I have a word document that is filled with DocVariables. What I am having trouble with is that I can't retrieve their names. What works for me now is this;

```
foreach(Field ff in aDoc.Fields)
{
    string txt = ff.Code.Text;
    //parse...
    //it returns {DOCVARIABLE PageCount \* MERGEFORMAT } but what I want is just PageCount.
}
```

I tried this;

```
foreach (Field ff in aDoc.Fields)
{
    if (ff.Type == WdFieldType.wdFieldDocVariable)
    {
        ff.Select();
        string s = ff.Result.Text;
    }
}
```

but it returns null. Can you please help me with this problem or is this what it should be like?

Comment: What is `DOCVARIABLE` and what sort of object is it?

Comment: It is a field variable in MS Word

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-docvariable-field-HP005189548.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if you got, as you said the string  `{DOCVARIABLE PageCount \* MERGEFORMAT }` you can do:

```
string str = txt.substring(1, txt.IndexOf(" "));
```

Comment: That is what I am doing right now but I wanted a more efficient and more professional way.

Comment: @Ada this is quite an efficient and professional way... unless you got xml file and want to deserialize it